# MS Access db.Execute " INSERT INTO

Tags: ms-access

can anyone write "db.Execute " INSERT INTO" command for below details.

Table name - Data_Load
Form name - Form1
take data from - Form1 - Cmb1 , txt1 , txt2
save to - Data_load = Style, Size1, Size 2

Answer (score 0):

Just bind your form (set its RecordSource) to Data_Load, and Cmb1, txt1, and txt2 to Style, Size1, Size2 respectively.

That's the way to do it in Access using a form.